# Retractable delta wing rocket

Tags: launch

I always wondered:
 would a 10,000 lb, 40 feet small rocket with retractable delta wings winched from a cargo plane,propelled by a jet similar to a f22 to mach 3 before igniting its own  rocket 
My question:  is how much fuel would i need  to get to space?

Comment: Why bother to retract the wings? Also how many airplanes are involved here, both a cargo plane and an f-22? More details please.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'm going to wait for the movie; though not yet sure if it's going to be a Daniel Craig or an Austin Powers.

Comment: AIU, he's proposing the rocket have a first stage that uses a jet engine (e.g. the F-119 engine as used on the F-22) instead of a rocket engine.

Comment: I was planning not to stay in space  i figured a pair of wings could be deployed after the high heat in re entry and glide home

Comment: I think you could start to use the "," character. It is used to separate clauses. You have a 4 line long sentence without a single ",". Nobody likes to decode it.

Comment: With a plane, a altitude of up to 30 km and a speed of up to mach 3 or about 1 km/s may be achieved, but for a low orbit a height of 300 to 400 km and a speed of about 8 km/s is necessary. That is 10 to 13 times the height and 8 times the speed. But 8 times the speed means 64 times the energy. Due to the tyranny of the rocket equation 64 times the energy means a lot more fuel.

Comment: Going to space is  a difficult task ,space junk is impossible to clean and will only get worse with time until a cheap and reliable a way is found for  mass producing a small rocket  operated not by NASA but an a section section of the air force may be the best alternative to deal with emergency rescues as well or meteorite deflection or ....space invateders

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed design isn't too much different from the [Pegasus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasus_(rocket)) rocket, although Pegasus is quite a bit heavier (18,500 kg=40,785 lb), the wing isn't retractable, and Pegasus doesn't use an initial jet engine.

Comment: Technically, Pegasus uses 3 jet engines in its first stage. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargazer_(aircraft)

Comment: but that would be the "Cargo plane" in the question, @RussellBorogove

Comment: Thank You Eugene, tjhe 10,000 lb would not include   the rocket fuel i have no idea how much fuel it would need

Comment: Thank You Eugene, tjhe 10,000 lb would not include   the rocket fuel i have no idea how much fuel it would need, the Cargo plane would be required to bring the small rocket to 40.000 feet  not sure if a mach 3 capable  plane could take off with a 10000 lb load plus fuel